# I need to update a record in mySQL using JDBC statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

But an exception is thrown: "java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()".

```
public void updateClientsMoney(String name, String password, Long transactValue) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("updateClientsMoney");

        String query = "";
        if(transactValue < 0) {
            query = String.format("UPDATE bank_client SET money %s where name = '%s'", transactValue, name);
        } else{
            query = String.format("UPDATE bank_client SET money %s where name = '%s'", transactValue, name);
        }

        try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
            statement.executeQuery(query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the reported issue this code

- searches the client by name which is unlikely to be a unique identifier - so this query will update money for all namesakes,
- has unused variable `password` (possibly it should have been used along with the `name`),
- does not use PreparedStatement which is a common best practice protecting from SQL injection,
- builds incorrect query which sets money to transactValue making `if` meaningless

Thus, it may be refactored this way:

```
public void updateClientsMoney(String clientId, Long transactValue) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("updateClientsMoney");
    String query = "UPDATE bank_client SET money = money + ? WHERE id = ?";

    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        statement.setLong  (1, transactValue.longValue());
        statement.setString(2, clientId);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

*Update: identifying client by name AND password*

```
public void updateClientsMoney(String name, String password, Long transactValue) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("updateClientsMoney");
    String query = "UPDATE bank_client SET money = money + ? WHERE name = ? AND password = ?";

    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        statement.setLong  (1, transactValue.longValue());
        statement.setString(2, name);
        statement.setString(3, password);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using executeQuery method for a DML statement i.e. Data Manipulation Statement. The operations such as INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE fall in this category. You need to update your code like below

```
public void updateClientsMoney(String name, String password, Long transactValue) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("updateClientsMoney");

    String query = "";
    if(transactValue < 0) {
        query = String.format("UPDATE bank_client SET money %s where name = '%s'", transactValue, name);
    } else{
        query = String.format("UPDATE bank_client SET money %s where name = '%s'", transactValue, name);
    }

    try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }
}
```